# Encrypt the connectionstring for Azure with VS2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption, azure, connection-string

I want to encrypt the connectionstring for my Azure ASP.Net Website.

I found the following article on the Windows Azure Blog: [Securing your connection string in Windows Azure - Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/09/09/securing-your-connection-string-in-windows-azure-part-3.aspx)

Unfortunately, the article seems to be outdated.

- Azure now works with the *.cer* file instead of *.pfx*, as the article states. (not a problem though)
- The linked [PKCS12 Provider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/pkcs12protectedconfg) cannot be built with Visual Studio 2012

When I try to open it in VS2012, I get the error that Installer.vdproj is incompatible and I therefor am unable to build the installer for the provider.

Is there an updated version of the provider somewhere?

Or is there another updated article on how to encrypt connection strings for Azure?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest the problem is with the installed project alone, the provider project itself builds just fine.
As all the installed seem to do is add the assembly to the Global Assembly Cache all you need to do is gacutil -i from an elevated command prompt to the provider's dll and everything else works just fine.